# Split the string into spaces

Tags: swift, string, split

I am try convert my double in string with space. Now i have number look like this 1234567.54 and i need get string like this "1 234 567.54" How i can do it in swift?

```
extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    mutating func insert(separator: String, every n: Int) {
        indices.reversed().forEach {
            if $0 != startIndex { if distance(from: startIndex, to: $0) % n == 0 { insert(contentsOf: separator, at: $0) } }
        }
    }
    func inserting(separator: String, every n: Int) -> Self {
        var string = self
        string.insert(separator: separator, every: n)
        return string
    }
}
```

Its work but not as much as I need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [NumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter) :

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.groupingSeparator = " "
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
let formattedNumber = formatter.string(from: 1234567.89)

print(formattedNumber)
```

> printed: 1 234 567.89